# EXE Programs ran with Wine show an empty or glitched dialog window

Tags: wine

(Version 8.0.1, NVIDIA driver 535) Hello, when I try opening any .exe file or simply running winecfg on the terminal I either get an empty or glitched window, even though I can still interact with it using TAB it just displays nothing.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDMy5.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7krtf.png

Comment: Given we have no basic software stack details (ie. what OS/release you're using) we'd only be guessing. Please provide your Ubuntu product & release details.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.